# How to do breakdown the code from App.js to the components

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am React js beginner so I dont do it accurately please help me anyone how to do it.

I need this completed app to be broken down into components named the following

```
https://github.com/Thinkful-Ed/laptop_customizer/tree/master/src
```

Summary

SummaryItem

FeatureItem

FeatureList

FeatureOption

State in app

This is what I have so far

```
https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-http-8qxo4
```

Thank you if anyone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to export any component you want. for example:

```
  const summary = Object.keys(this.state.selected).map((feature, idx) => {
  const featureHash = feature + '-' + idx;
  const selectedOption = this.state.selected[feature];

  return (
    <div className="summary__option" key={featureHash}>
      <div className="summary__option__label">{feature} </div>
      <div className="summary__option__value">{selectedOption.name}</div>
      <div className="summary__option__cost">
        {USCurrencyFormat.format(selectedOption.cost)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
});
```

can change to:

```
export const Summary = ({ feature, idx, selectedOption}) => {
  const featureHash = feature + '-' + idx;

  return (
    <div className="summary__option" key={featureHash}>
      <div className="summary__option__label">{feature} </div>
      <div className="summary__option__value">{selectedOption.name}</div>
      <div className="summary__option__cost">
        {USCurrencyFormat.format(selectedOption.cost)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and you can use it in your main render method like this:

```
{Object.keys(this.state.selected).map((feature, idx) => {
  return (
    <Summary
      feature={feature}
      selectedOption={this.state.selected[feature]}
      idx={idx}
    />
  );
})}
```

Best practice is to habe your Summary component code in different file, like summary.js.

You can try this for other components as well.

Comment: kindly do it for all please i am beginner

Comment: Stack overflow is for question and answer. I'll make a pull request in your Github repository if i had time.

Comment: Thank you I understand so no need of this